# error running tox for airflow

Tags: kerberos, tox, airflow

Trying to contribute to airflow but cannot get tox up and running on Ubuntu 16.0.4.  Something is going on with kerbos.

https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow

```
py34-hdp-airflow_backend_postgres runtests: commands[2] | sudo /home/dalupus/incubator-airflow/scripts/ci/setup_kdc.sh
WARNING:test command found but not installed in testenv
  cmd: /usr/bin/sudo
  env: /home/dalupus/incubator-airflow/.tox/py34-hdp-airflow_backend_postgres
Maybe you forgot to specify a dependency? See also the whitelist_externals envconfig setting.
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   ubuntu

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
hostname: ubuntu
Loading random data
Initializing database '/etc/krb5kdc/principal' for realm 'TEST.LOCAL',
master key name 'K/M@TEST.LOCAL'
You will be prompted for the database Master Password.
It is important that you NOT FORGET this password.
Enter KDC database master key: 
Re-enter KDC database master key to verify: 
kdb5_util: File exists while creating database '/etc/krb5kdc/principal'
Authenticating as principal root/admin@TEST.LOCAL with password.
WARNING: no policy specified for admin/admin@TEST.LOCAL; defaulting to no policy
Enter password for principal "admin/admin@TEST.LOCAL": 
Re-enter password for principal "admin/admin@TEST.LOCAL": 
add_principal: Principal or policy already exists while creating "admin/admin@TEST.LOCAL".
Authenticating as principal root/admin@TEST.LOCAL with password.
WARNING: no policy specified for airflow@TEST.LOCAL; defaulting to no policy
add_principal: Principal or policy already exists while creating "airflow@TEST.LOCAL".
Authenticating as principal root/admin@TEST.LOCAL with password.
WARNING: no policy specified for airflow/ubuntu@TEST.LOCAL; defaulting to no policy
add_principal: Principal or policy already exists while creating "airflow/ubuntu@TEST.LOCAL".
Authenticating as principal root/admin@TEST.LOCAL with password.
Usage: ktadd [-k[eytab] keytab] [-q] [-e keysaltlist] [-norandkey] [principal | -glob princ-exp] [...]
Authenticating as principal root/admin@TEST.LOCAL with password.
Usage: ktadd [-k[eytab] keytab] [-q] [-e keysaltlist] [-norandkey] [principal | -glob princ-exp] [...]
chmod: missing operand after ‘664’
Try 'chmod --help' for more information.
ERROR: InvocationError: '/usr/bin/sudo /home/dalupus/incubator-airflow/scripts/ci/setup_kdc.sh'
```

Not sure where to even start with this.  I think I have installed all the deps.

Comment: Please add alink to the project. It's not a problem with tox BTW.

Comment: yes I don't think it is a "problem" with tox, I am sure it is config issue.

Comment: @Dalupus Did you find a solution to this? I'm getting the same thing, in Travis CI builds for Airflow (https://travis-ci.org/ahh2131/incubator-airflow/jobs/285393754#L8831)

Comment: @andy-hadjigeorgiou I did not but I looked at your error log and it is different.   You are running into an error with the Docker stuff.  there was an error that was accidentally put into master which has been fixed.  If you rebase the error should go away.

Answer (score 1):

The script `scripts/ci/setup_kdc.sh` is run under `sudo` and `sudo` clears environment variables, so `${KRB5_KTNAME}` is not defined.

The command `sudo` is used in `tox.ini` but `tox` doesn't find it in its virtual environments (of course it doesn't — `sudo` is a system command that shouldn't be installed in a venv.) The command must be whitelisted in `tox.ini` in the section `[testenv]`:

```
[testenv]
whitelist_externals =
    sudo
```

These are bugs in `airflow`, please send them a pull request or a bug report.

Comment: hmm ... can that really be the problem? AFAIK If a program is not whitelisted, it will still work but tox will print a warning that you should whitelist it.

Comment: @OliverBestwalter You're right. I extended the answer. Thanks.